# Spring AMQP StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor not used

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-retry

I am trying configure spring amqp to only retry a message a defined amount of times. Currently a message that fails e.g. because of a `DataIntegrityViolationException`  is redelivered indefinitely.

According to the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#retry) I came up with the following configuration

```
@Bean
    public StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor() {
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder.stateful()
                .backOffOptions(1000, 2.0, 10000) // initialInterval, multiplier, maxInterval
                .maxAttempts(3)
                .messageKeyGenerator(message -> UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }
```

This does not seem to be applied - the messages are still tried indefinitely.

Feels like I am missing something here.

Here is my remaining configuration regarding AMQP:

```
@Bean
    Queue testEventSubscriberQueue() {
        final boolean durable = true;
        return new Queue("testEventSubscriberQueue", durable);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(TopicExchange topicExchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(testEventSubscriberQueue()).to(topicExchange).with("payload.event-create");
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(testEventSubscriberQueue().getName());
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setChannelTransacted(true);
        return container;
    }


    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(MessageConverter messageConverter, SubscriberHandler subscriberHandler) {
        MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter = new MessageListenerAdapter(subscriberHandler);
        listenerAdapter.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        return listenerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter messageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        final Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        jsonMessageConverter.setJsonObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        DefaultClassMapper defaultClassMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        defaultClassMapper.setDefaultType(EventPayload.class);
        jsonMessageConverter.setClassMapper(defaultClassMapper);
        final ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter messageConverter = new ContentTypeDelegatingMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter);
        messageConverter.addDelgate(MessageProperties.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON, jsonMessageConverter);
        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        //rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }

@Bean
    public TopicExchange testExchange() {
        final boolean durable = true;
        final boolean autoDelete = false;
        return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME, durable, autoDelete);
    }
```

I am using spring-amqp 1.5.1.RELEASE.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to configure the container to add the interceptor to its advice chain...

```
container.setAdviceChain(new Advice[] { statefulRetryOperationsInterceptor() });
```

Comment: Note that using a random UUID as the message key is not very useful - we can't track the number of retries; the message key needs to be something unique in the message. If the originating system is Spring AMQP, it can be configured to set a message id in the message headers. If you don't have a unique id, consider using stateless retry, which does not involve redelivery.

Comment: Do you know, why there is no example code in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#async-listeners)?

Comment: There's a code example for creating a retry interceptor and the text says to add it to the container's advice chain; open a GitHub issue if you feel further clarification is required. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues